# Laravel Datatable delete record with sweetalert dont working

Tags: laravel, datatable, sweetalert

I am using DataTables and Sweetalert but I have a problem, after confirmation in Sweetalert, nothing is deleted and I get 2 errors.

My controller(index & destroy):

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = User::select('id','firstName')->get();
        return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addColumn('action', 'partials.column')->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }
    return view('admin.users.index');
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    User::find($id)->delete();
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Item deleted successfully.']);
}
```

Partials.column(blade)

```
<td><a href="#" class="dropdown-item deleteItem"  data-id="" data-action="" onclick="deleteConfirmation()"><i class="bx bx-trash mr-1"></i> delete</a></td>
```

and js code

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            var s, e = [];
            0 < $("#users-list-datatable").length && (s = $("#users-list-datatable").DataTable({
                order: [[0, "desc"]],
                pageLength: 10,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: false,
                language: {
                    'loadingRecords': '&nbsp;',
                    'processing': '<div class="spinner-border text-light spinner-border-lg"></div>'
                },
                ajax: "{{ route('admin.users.index')}}",
                columns: [
                    {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                    {data: 'firstName', name: 'firstName'},
                    {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},

                ],

            }))

        });


        function deleteConfirmation(id) {
            swal({
                title: "Delete?",
                text: "Please ensure and then confirm!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: !0,
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                cancelButtonText: "No, cancel!",
                reverseButtons: !0
            }).then(function (e) {
                if (e.value === true) {
                    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'DELETE',
                        url: "{{ route('admin.users.destroy','') }}"+'/'+id,
                        data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        success: function (results) {
                            if (results.success === true) {
                                swal("Done!", results.message, "success");
                            } else {
                                swal("Error!", results.message, "error");
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    e.dismiss;
                }
            }, function (dismiss) {
                return false;
            })
        }
```

### show this errors

> DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/undefined 500 (Internal
> Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

The 405 means that your route isn't accepting that method. You need to check that the route /admin/users is able to use the delete method

```
Route::delete($uri, $callback);
```

You can see more on routing at the following page:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing

However you might also need to clear the route cache with

```
php artisan route:cache
```